# Почему функция enumerate() работает неправильно при сохранении результатов цикла в excel?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Почему функция enumerate() работает неправильно при сохранении результатов цикла в excel с помощью openpyxl?[image: что получается] [image: как хотелось бы]

```
import openpyxl

wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('импорт2.xlsx')
ws2 = wb2['Разделы 1-2']

for i in range(17):
    if i == 0:
        continue
    elif i == 1:
        for j,k in enumerate('abc'): 
            ws2.cell(row=j + 4, column=3).value = '201' + k 
    elif i == 8:
        for jj,h in enumerate('abcd'):
            ws2.cell(row=jj + 13, column=3).value = '208' + h 
    elif i < 10:
        ws2.cell(row=i + 4, column=3).value = '20' + str(i) 
    elif i >= 10:
        ws2.cell(row=i + 4, column=3).value = '2'+ str(i)

wb2.save(filename='импорт2.xlsx')
```

Comment: Код в цикле выполняется ОДИН раз. Когда ``i`` равно 1. Где стоит print, который работает правильно?

Comment: Что у вас является ожидаемым результатом? Что именно работает не так, как вы ожидаете?

Comment: нумерация должна идти последовательно с присвоением букв, а получается то какая-то нумерация пропадает, то буквы не все добавляются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вся нумерация у вас идёт последовательно, и буквы правильно проставляются. Просто вы со смещением строк немного намудрили (это когда вы к `row` прибавляете 4 или 13). В результате у вас кое-где строчки перезаписались там, где перед этим уже был записан результат, а кое-где пропуски получились.

Я решил всю часть с записью в ячейки целиком переписать, так как ваш код было бы очень муторно приводить к рабочему виду.

Получилось вот так:

```
import openpyxl

wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('импорт2.xlsx')
ws2 = wb2['Разделы 1-2']

letters = {
    201: 'abc',
    208: 'abcd'
}

r = 4  # start row
for num in range(201, 216+1):
    for letter in letters.get(num, ('',)):
        ws2.cell(row=r, column=3).value = str(num) + letter
        r += 1

wb2.save(filename='импорт2.xlsx')
```

У меня не установлен `openpyxl` и проверить на работоспособность я не могу, но вроде бы должно работать.

Comment: Спасибо большое, все прекрасно работает как надо!

Comment: @user327535, пожалуйста, всегда рад помочь. Только в следующий раз лучше сразу максимально подробно описывайте проблему :))

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/971556/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%8B  я создала вопрос, на основе вашего кода - помогите пожалуйста. Мне нужен код именно с условиями, т.к. нужно в середину будет еще добавить постоянно меняющуюся переменную из др экселевской книги - в коде я  эту переменную. не указала, чтоб код был проще,вот зачем нужны условия