# Почему функция enumerate() работает неправильно при сохранении результатов цикла в excel с помощью openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Почему функция enumerate() работает неправильно при сохранении результатов цикла в excel с помощью openpyxl?[image: так получается] [image: и как хотелось бы]

```
import openpyxl

wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('импорт2.xlsx')
ws2 = wb2['Разделы 1-2']

for i in range(17):
    if i == 0:
        continue
    elif i == 1:
        for j,k in enumerate('abc'): 
            ws2.cell(row=j + 4, column=3).value = '201' + k 
    elif i == 8:
        for jj,h in enumerate('abcd'):
            ws2.cell(row=jj + 4, column=3).value = '208' + h 
    elif i < 10:
        ws2.cell(row=i + 4, column=3).value = '20' + str(i) 
    elif i >= 10:
        ws2.cell(row=i + 4, column=3).value = '2'+ str(i)

wb2.save(filename='импорт2.xlsx')
```

Comment: Дубль https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/971300/Почему-функция-enumerate-работает-неправильно-при-сохранении-результатов-цикла