# Почему при выполнении цикла не добавляются буквы?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Почему при выполнении цикла не добавляются буквы?

```
import openpyxl

wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('импорт2.xlsx')
ws2 = wb2['Разделы 1-2']

letters = {
    201: 'abc',
    208: 'abcd'
}

r = 4  # start row
for num in range(1, 16):
    if num<10:
        for letter in letters.get(num, ('',)):
            ws2.cell(row=r, column=3).value = '2'+ '0'+ str(num) + letter
            r += 1
    elif num>=10:
        ws2.cell(row=r, column=3).value = '2' + str(num)
        r += 1



wb2.save(filename='импорт2.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что вы сломали тот код, который я написал в предыдущем вопросе :))

В скобках у `range` должны быть именно те числа, которые нужно вывести. То есть от 201 до 216+1 (range не включает последнее число в диапазоне, поэтому нужно прибавлять единицу).

Буквы берутся именно по этому номеру из словарика letters. Вы же заменили числа в range, но словарик оставили прежним. Поэтому код теперь перебирает числа от 1 до 16, но в словарике буквы только для чисел 201 и 208, и код их не берёт.

Comment: эти же числа создаются, я думала, что если создаются - значит добавляются и буковки =))  все же не понимаю, как сделать, так чтобы цикл заработал с такими условиями.

Comment: Потому что буковки берутся для переменной num. А у вас num от 1 до 16, а буковки есть только для 201 и 208. А для от 1 до 16 нет буковок. Если вам очень хочется по вашему - вы можете поправить словарь letters, чтобы там были буковки для 1 и 8. Либо сначала вычислять итоговый номер в отдельную переменную и брать из словарика буквы уже для этого итогового номера. Только при этом учитывайте, что у вас итоговый номер вычисляется как строка, а в словарике ключи - числа.

Comment: Просто не понятно, чем вам не угодил мой код. Если он не покрывает какие-то дополнительные задачи, которые вы не описали в вопросах, то напишите эти задачи мне в личку, я помогу вам его допилить.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/971634/%D0%A3%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C  создала новый вопрос - посмотрите, пожалуйста?))

Comment: @user327535, вечером смогу посмотреть

Comment: все, все  уже объяснили, спасибо =)