# Условия не срабатывают, не понимаю как исправить

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Этот код работает не так, как хотелось бы, не понимаю как исправить? Нужно, чтобы нумерация была такой:

```
20301a
20301b
20301c
20302
20303
...
20308a
20308b 
20308c
20308d
20309 
20310
20311
20312
...
20369

import openpyxl

wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('импорт2.xlsx')
ws2 = wb2['Разделы 1-2']

обязательная_переменная = '03'

for i in range(70):
    if i==0:
        continue
    elif i==1:
        for g in 'abc':
           ws2.cell(row = 4+i, column = 3).value='2'+ обязательная_переменная +'01'+g
    elif i==8:
        for h in 'abcd':
            ws2.cell(row = 4+i, column = 3).value='2'+ обязательная_переменная +'08'+h
    elif i<10:
        ws2.cell(row = 4+i, column = 3).value='2'+ обязательная_переменная +'0'+str(i)
    elif i>=10:
        ws2.cell(row = 4+i, column = 3).value='2'+ обязательная_переменная +str(i)


wb2.save(filename='импорт2.xlsx')
```

Comment: Минусующие, вопрос вполне понятен. Если он не понятен вам, то увы и ах

Comment: Рад, что смог помочь. В следующий раз приводите не только ожидаемый, но и тот вывод, который ошибочный. Это сильно поможет отвечающим, а Вам позволит избежать  минусов за вопрос

Comment: спасибо, хорошо =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте отдельную переменную для счётчика вставленных строк - `j`

```
import openpyxl

wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('импорт2.xlsx')
ws2 = wb2['Разделы 1-2']

обязательная_переменная = '03'

j = 0
for i in range(70):
    if i==0:
        continue
    elif i==1:
        for g in 'abc':
           ws2.cell(row = 4+j, column = 3).value='2'+ обязательная_переменная +'01'+g
           j+=1
    elif i==8:
        for h in 'abcd':
            ws2.cell(row = 4+j, column = 3).value='2'+ обязательная_переменная +'08'+h
            j+= 1
    elif i<10:
        ws2.cell(row = 4+j, column = 3).value='2'+ обязательная_переменная +'0'+str(i)
        j+=1
    elif i>=10:
        ws2.cell(row = 4+j, column = 3).value='2'+ обязательная_переменная +str(i)
        j+=1


wb2.save(filename='импорт2.xlsx')
```

Comment: все заработало, ура!!! спасибо большое =))